# Constrained linear regression through a specified point

Tags: r, regression

I have a point (x,y) that I need a linear regressor to pass through given a data set (X,Y). How do I implement this in R?

Comment: @cardinal Good answer!  (Maybe you could post it as a reply?)

Comment: @cardinal.  Right on the money.  Please post this as an answer -- let's minimize the number of unanswered questions.  :O)  Ps. Up-votes headed your way.

Comment: Thank you cardinal. By the way, is there a way to force the regression line to have a negative slope?

Comment: If the fitted line does not have a negative slope, the best you can do is a zero slope, which will pass through the point $(x,y)$, thereby uniquely determining it.

Comment: I have deleted my comment and expanded it slightly into a full answer.

Comment: While this doesn't use R, for others who found this question and need a more general answer, here is an interactive example I made in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0ejtjkz6hh
(by slope) https://www.desmos.com/calculator/389wfvp3w0
(by angle)

Comment: The general question "pass through a data set" (instead of just one point) was asked again a couple years later and answered fully at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50447.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If $(x_0,y_0)$ is the point through which the regression line must pass, fit the model $y−y_0=\beta (x−x_0)+\varepsilon$, i.e., a linear regression with "no intercept" on a translated data set. In $R$, this might look like `lm( I(y-y0) ~ I(x-x0) + 0)`. Note the `+ 0` at the end which indicates to `lm` that no intercept term should be fit.

Depending on how easily you are convinced, there are multiple ways to demonstrate that this does, indeed, yield the correct answer. If you want to establish it formally, one simple method is to use Lagrange multipliers.

Whether or not it is actually a *good idea* to force a regression line to go through a particular point is a separate matter and is problem dependent. Generally, I would personally caution against this, unless there is a very good reason (e.g., *very* strong theoretical considerations). For one thing, fitting the full model can provide a means for measuring lack of fit. As a second matter, if you are mostly interested in evaluating model explanatory power for values of $x$ and $y$ "far away" from $(x_0,y_0)$, then the relevance of the fixed point becomes suspect.