# Simple linear regression -- through a specific point

Tags: regression, linear-model

In follow up to a question posted here: [Constrained linear regression through a specified point](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12484/constrained-linear-regression-through-a-specified-point/12511#12511)

What are some ways that we can tell if a simple linear regression model is "good" when we constrain it through a specified point?

Comment: What about "classical" testing, i.e. as a ratio of explained / unexplained variance and using F test?

Answer (score 5):

Since forcing a regression line through a certain point means imposing constraints on the coefficients, you can do an $F$-test (R: `anova`) to compare the constrained and unconstrained models. And since this is still a regression model, the traditional stuff like residual diagnostics should make sense, at least partially: the residuals would not sum up to zero, for instance.