# Constraining regression coefficients using inequalities the easy way?

Tags: regression, python, constrained-regression

I want to do something very simple. I have a regression:

```
y = b0 + b1*X1 + b2*X2 + b3*X3
```

and the resulting coefficients must be constrained by:

```
b1 < b2 < b3
```

Is there any easy way to implement this in standard Python or R regression packages?

Comment: This post may be helpful
[enter link description here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21565/how-do-i-fit-a-constrained-regression-in-r-so-that-coefficients-total-1)