# Can I change the constant in the response surface regression?

Tags: regression, minitab

I analyzed my data using response surface regression using Minitab. the constant is the model is very close to one of the material properties (strength). I would like to keep the constant at a certain value and run the regression. Is there any way to do so?
Thank you

Comment: You can make the surface pass through any predetermined set of points that can be fit without error.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/50464/919 for the method (illustrated with polynomial responses, but applicable generally).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the method. I think I got the concept, but when I run it in minitab, it is still gives a constant. Not sure if there is a way to do supress the constant and do regression without it.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way--all statistical regression software gives you the option to suppress the constant.  You should be able to find out in the help manual.