Fitting a regression line which passes through the anchor point
In our setting, we have data $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, which can be ordered as $X_{1,n}\leq X_{2,n}\leq \ldots \leq X_{n,n}$ and we have the points $(-\log (1-\frac{i}{n+1}), X_{i,n})$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.
In particular, let our anchor point be $(-\log \frac{k+1}{n+1}, X_{n-k,n})$, which is the point with $i = n-k$. We want to estimate the slope of the least regression line going through the anchor point, only considering points to the right of this anchor point.
The text then says that we need to minimize(with respect to $m$)
$$\sum_{j=1}^k (\log \frac{k+1}{j})^{-1} (X_{n-j+1,n}- [X_{n-k,n}+m(\log \frac{n+1}{j} - \log \frac{n+1}{k+1})])^2$$
However, I don't understand why we're scaling by the factor of $(\log \frac{k+1}{j})^{-1}$.
Shouldn't we just minimize
$$\sum_{j=1}^k (X_{n-j+1,n}- [X_{n-k,n}+m(\log \frac{n+1}{j} - \log \frac{n+1}{k+1})])^2$$
?
Thank you.



The text is: Albrecher, H., Beirlant, J. and Teugels, J. (2017). Reinsurance: Actuarial and Statistical Aspects, Wiley, Chichester. It's from section 4.1 of the book.
To be more precise using the text, the text says that "When fitting a regression line which passes through the anchor point using least square minimizing". I interpret the text as saying "fit a least square linear regression line going through the anchor point, using only the points to the right of the anchor point". But under this interpretation, I think the objective function in the text is wrong.

Doesn't https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50447 answer your question?  I can't tell, because it's unclear whether it's about constraining the regression or about QQ plots (which is a different issue!).

@whuber it's about constrained regression. I don't think the question linked answers my question because here I'm just not certain how to justify the optimization problem proposed in the text.

I don't understand what you mean by "justify," because the text isn't specifically about constrained regression: it merely points out that if one adopts a specific objective function, its solution is the expression that one "indeed obtains" at the end of the quotation.

@whuber  So what I don't understand is why we're using that specific objective function. I'd think if we were just doing least square regression while specifying that the line has to go through the anchor point, the objective function ought to be $\sum_{j=1}^k (X_{n-j+1,n}- [X_{n-k,n}+m(\log \frac{n+1}{j} - \log \frac{n+1}{k+1})])^2$, not the one specified in the text.

But using that objective function wouldn't yield the intended solution! Although the full context isn't in evidence, it appears the text is working backwards from the solution to the objective function, not the other way around.

@whuber The text says to fit a least square regression line with the line going through $(-\log \frac{k+1}{n+1}), X_{n-k,n})$ no? But my problem is that I can't see how the objective function is for fitting a least square regression line going through the point $(-\log \frac{k+1}{n+1}), X_{n-k,n})$.

The least-squares objective function is explicitly weighted.

@whuber what's the intuitive meaning of the weights?

They are inversely proportional to the distances between the quantiles and the base quantile.  Thus, the data closest to the "anchor" get more weight, thereby focusing the fit.
