# Name of transformation that maps numbers outside of interval onto endpoints?

Tags: terminology

I am looking for the term for a transformation that maps numbers outside of an interval onto the endpoints:

My interval is $[a,b]$. Any number $x < a$ will be transformed to $a$ and any number $y > b$ will be transformed to $b$.

Is there a term for these kind of functions?

Comment: It's definitely a piecewise-linear transformation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function#Examples) but I don't know if we can get more specific

Comment: I guess you mean $\max(a, \min(x, b))$ or $\min(\max(x, a), b) $ i.e. that $x$ is returned  if within $[a, b]$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I'm looking for the name...

Comment: I've seen this called clipping. I wouldn't vouch for that being a universal or even standard name, but it is available.

Comment: It is called the hardtanh in the ML community, though I do no know the origin of it. See for instance https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Hardtanh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It will depend on the context.**

- I recall the term ["clamping" being used.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics))    It appears in various disciplines including numerical optimization and computer graphics.
- In the computer graphics area this is needed to distinguish it from an important, ubiquitous, but different operation called ["clipping"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(computer_graphics))
- Despite that, ["clipping" is used in signal processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(signal_processing)) to denote your operation.
- There is a closely allied operation in statistics called ["Winsorizing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing).  Winsorizing can be construed as beginning with a data-dependent clipping operation.

[image: Graph]

This graph of the "clipping" or "clamping" operation was created by plotting the function $x \to a \vee (b\wedge x)$ (where $\vee$ is the maximum and $\wedge$ is the minimum).  It visually demonstrates that

1. Clamping is piecewise linear.
2. It can be construed as a special form of linear ["spline"](https://gerardnico.com/data_mining/linear_spline) connecting the points $(a,a)$ and $(b,b).$  (Applying affine transformations to either or both coordinate will transform it into a linear spline between any pair of distinct points.)  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/291598/919 for the theory and code.

Comment: WInsorizing is pulling inwards for pre-specified fractions of the values in the tails of a sample according to chosen fractions (e.g. the highest and lowest 5%; in general,  fractions could differ, so that either fraction could be zero). It's not about clipping according to a pre-specified value or values. While it remains true that definitions can be made wide sense and extended beyond their first use, I think clipping is the better term here.

Comment: @Nick Agreed. That is why I have not proposed that this operation actually is *termed* "Winsorizing."  It looked useful to drag this concept into the discussion because it makes the applicability of the question to statistics a little more apparent.  BTW, I have long preferred "clamping" for the name due to the overloading of "clipping" in related domains.

Comment: @Nick Hmm, I see the OP was not the person who added the [tag:Winsorizing] tag.  I have rolled back that edit so this thread better reflects the original intentions.

Comment: Let's try to clamp down on clipping, then.