# How to efficiently fit a spline with a linear piece between two constant pieces

Tags: python, splines, change-point

I have two dimensional data, to which I'd like to fit a spline function.
A spline would be defined as this:

- `y_0` for `x`<=`x_0`
- `y_0` + `a` * (`x`-`x_0`) for `x_0`<=`x`<=`x_1`
- `y_1` = `y_0` + `a` * (`x_1`-`x_0`) for `x`>=`x_1`

So, constant line -> linear function -> constant line.

I want to find out values of `x_0`, `x_1`, `y_0` and `a` minimising RMSE (or otherwise fitting well). How can I do this efficiently in Python?

Comment: Because this is a variation of the question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291436, you will likely find at least one of the many answers there to be helpful.  The principal complication concerns estimating $x_0,$ which does not appear within the model in a linear fashion: this requires a nonlinear fitting method, such as profile likelihood (or its least squares equivalent).  As you might surmise from the referenced thread, creating a fully general and correct program for this *changepoint problem* is not a small matter: it would be best to find existing Python code.

Comment: @whuber that's true in general, but in this case where there are only two changepoints to estimate we may be in luck if the OP's data is not overwhelmingly large: we can simply exhaustively try a fine grid of values $\underset{j}{\min}(\mathbf{x}_j)\leq x_0 \leq x_1 \leq \underset{j}{\max}(\mathbf{x}_j)$, implemented via a nested for loop, taking advantage of profile least squares as you advocate. Whether or not this qualifies as "efficient" as the OP requests depends; I simply note that this approach is embarrassingly parallel.

Comment: @John That would be easy to implement and parallel, as you say.  In terms of total computation, deploying a nonlinear optimizer would likely be the most efficient.